# Laravel function query() "pagination does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, controller

Just wondering where to position the Laravel's `pagination()` here in my `query()` in order for it to work. I tried adding it at the end of `$all_procedures`:

```php
public function fetchprocedure(Request $search_procedure) {
    $filter_procedure = $search_procedure->input('search_procedure');
    $all_procedures = HmsBbrKnowledgebaseProcedure::query()
        ->when(is_null($filter_procedure), function ($query) {
            $query->where('bbr_procedure_id', '>=', 1);
        })
        //iLike is case insensitive
        ->when(!empty($filter_procedure), function ($query) use ($filter_procedure) {
            $query->where('procedure_name', 'iLIKE', "%$filter_procedure%");
        })
        ->orderBy('bbr_procedure_id', 'ASC')
        ->get()
        ->paginate(10);

    return response()->json([
        'all_procedures' => $all_procedures,
    ]);
}
```

[image: Error]

**UPDATE:**
tried a solution given by an answer. Got rid of `get();` but my error this time is:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just instead of having:

```php
->get()
->paginate(10);
```

Do

```php
->paginate(10);
```

That will automatically get `10` results and paginate it taking into account the current page.

Comment: now I am getting a `Cannot read property of null` error, updated my question

Comment: That new error is a `javascript` error, show us your Javascript files or mark this answer as correct and create a new question.